# why is data.table not exporting its methods

Tags: r, data.table

`data.table` doesn't export its methods like `unique` or `split`:

```
> data.table::split
Error: 'split' is not an exported object from 'namespace:data.table'
```

However, other packages seem to do so.`forecast::forecast()` for example is exported, like `forecast::accuracy()`, even though based on `generics` functions.

My question,

*Why is data.table not exporting these methods while at least some other packages seem to do so. Is there a technical reason apart from being an arbitrary choice made by the author, and what would be best practice here?*

Moreover, split is both in the `data.table` manual and its index. If the author clearly doesn't mind about this method being visible, why not export it?

[image]

by the way, `urca::summary()`is exported, but that might be understandable if `S4` methods should be exported to override `S3` objects.

Comment: split is a method, not a function. as a method it, I believe, is exported/registered.

Comment: I edited the question which is now clearer

Comment: https://blog.r-hub.io/2019/12/12/internal-functions/#:~:text=Why%20not%20export%20all%20functions,great%20care%20if%20need%20be.

Comment: S3 methods need to be registered as S3 methods for dispatch to work properly, but it is not required that they be exported. For instance, `split` and `unique` are not exported from `data.table`, yet they are registered and work; `print` is not exported from `tibble`, but `print.tbl_df` is called when a tibble needs to be rendered. However, `stats::predict.lm` _is_ exported (as well as registered). Why is `split` (and other funcs from `data.table`) not exported? Because that is how the authors set up the package, whether deliberate (to not export) or not taking deliberate action to export.

Comment: perhaps. hence my question as to `is there a technical reason` apart from the author's choice or not

Comment: As I wrote in a previous comment (now removed), it may be difficult to answer _why_-questions related to design decisions made by package developers. However, in the particular case of `split.data.table` we get some insights in the arguments for export (or not). See Notes in [`data.table` 1.11.18 NEWS](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/blob/master/NEWS.md#datatable-v1118--30-sep-2018): "`split.data.table` was exported in v1.11.6 in addition to being registered using `S3method(split, data.table)`."

Comment: "The export has been removed again. It had been added because a user said they found it difficult to find, #2920. But _S3 methods are not normally exported explicitly by packages_ [my emphasis]. The proper way to access the `split.data.table` method is to call `split(DT)` where `DT` is a `data.table`. The generic (`base::split` in this case) then dispatches to the `split.data.table` method."

Comment: Similary, in [`data.table` 1.12.4](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/blob/master/NEWS.md#datatable-v1124--03-oct-2019), NEW FEATURES, on `merge.data.table` where the authors decided to export: "`merge.data.table` is now exported, #2618. _We realize that S3 methods should not ordinarily be exported_ [my emphasis]. Rather, the method should be invoked via S3 dispatch. But users continue to request its export, perhaps because of intricacies relating to the fact that `data.table` inherits from `data.frame``"

Comment: Now we're talking: *split.data.table method is now properly exported, #2920. But we don't recommend it because split copies all the pieces into new memory.*

Comment: @gaut I assume that's an argument against splitting a data table into pieces _in general_, rather than an argument for/against exporting.

Comment: right, and it might be  one of the reasons why Matt & co. didn't export it: *they don't recommend using `split` at all*, since it is not optimized the same way as other data.table functions.

Comment: @gaut No, please read `?split.data.table`: "Split method for `data.table`. _Faster_ and more flexible. Be aware that processing list of data.tables will be generally much slower than manipulation in single data.table by group using `by` argument". It's the second sentence (not `split.data.table` itself) which is the reason for "_But we don't recommend it_" in the NEWS.

Comment: that's what I meant: not exporting the method might direct users towards their recommended approach. Although they could also have hidden the manual page at least from the index if they wanted to reduce visibility

Comment: but I suppose the main reason might be that they're considering that `S3 methods should not ordinarily be exported`, as pointed out

Comment: Great discussion here. I think it is more a question about R pkgs, not data.table. DT can adjust on that matter to what R recommended way will be. AFAIK there is no any, so the behavior is rather random, depending on requests from community.

Comment: @Henrik Let's close this post as too broad, or move your valuable comments into an answer?